# The best overload method for '... ' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I created a player class and I am trying to use my player class to create and insert a player for my menu driven player program but I keep the error: 
***The best overload method for 'Assignment_7.Program.GetInsertIndex(int Assignment_7.Player, ref int)' has some invalid arguments*** with my InsertPlayer and my ProcessCreate method.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 static void ProcessCreate(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals,
        Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
    {

        if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's number");
            number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (GetPlayerIndex(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, playerCount) == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's First Name");
                 firstName = Console.ReadLine();
                 Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's First Name");
                 lastName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's goals");
                goals = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's goals");
                assists = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                InsertPlayer(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: Number - {0}, First Name - {1},LastName - {2} Goals - {3}, Assists {4} created successfully", number,firstName, lastName, goals, assists);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player number already exists");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player roster is already full");

    }


    //Inserts the player at the correct location in the tables based on order of ascending player number
    //Unless the insert location is at the end, this requires shifting existing players down in order to make room 
    //Inserts the player at the correct location in the tables based on order of ascending player number
    //Unless the insert location is at the end, this requires shifting existing players down in order to make room 
    static Int32 InsertPlayer(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals,
        Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount)
    {
        Int32 insertIndex, shiftCount;
   ---> insertIndex = GetInsertIndex(number, players, playerCount); <--- Error
        for (shiftCount = playerCount; shiftCount > insertIndex; shiftCount--)
            players[shiftCount] = players[shiftCount - 1];
        players[insertIndex] = new Player(firstName, lastName, number, goals, assists);
        playerCount++;
        return insertIndex;
    }





    //Returns the index of the first player number in the table that is greater
    //than the player number to be inserted
    static Int32 GetInsertIndex(Int32 number,Player[] players,
        ref Int32 playerCount)
    {
        Int32 index = 0;
        bool found = false;
        while (index < playerCount && found == false)
            if (players[index].Number > number)
                found = true;
              else
                index++;
        return index;
    }

    //Returns the index of the player number in the table 
    //or -1 if the number is not found
    static Int32 GetPlayerIndex(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals,
        Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount)
    {
        Int32 index = 0;
        bool found = false;
        while (index < playerCount && found == false)
             if (players[index].Number == number)
                found = true;
              else
                index++;
        if (found == false)
            index = -1;
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: Neither of the overloads is compatible with `GetInsertIndex(number, players, playerCount);`. Perhaps you meant `GetInsertIndex(number, players, ref playerCount);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx), `ref` must be used both on declaration and invocation

> To use a ref parameter, both the method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the ref keyword...

So, in your case, you should replace

```
insertIndex = GetInsertIndex(number, players, playerCount);
```

with

```
insertIndex = GetInsertIndex(number, players, ref playerCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `GetInsertIndex` expects last parameter with `ref` modifier, but you are passing it by value. You should add `ref` before passed argument:

```
insertIndex = GetInsertIndex(number, players, ref playerCount);
//                                      here  ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ref` in your method argument must use that in invocation. then replace

```
insertIndex = GetInsertIndex(number, players, playerCount);
```

with

```
insertIndex = GetInsertIndex(number, players, ref playerCount);
```